# Rust syntax: assignment to underscore without let

Tags: rust

For a few Rust versions now, one can do `_ = foo()` instead of `let _ = foo()` in assignments. However, I can not recall the name of this syntax and can't find official documentation for it. I also don't find the PR in the rustlang repo. Can anyone provide some context, please?

Answer (score 4):

It is part of the [destructuring assignment](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2909-destructuring-assignment.html) RFC, that allows pattern to be used for assignments and not just variable declaration. [Stabilized in Rust 1.59.0](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/02/24/Rust-1.59.0.html#destructuring-assignments).

Comment: When did that ship?